# How to detect XSS in Java using OWASP

Tags: java, security, jsoup, xss, owasp

I have this thing which I'm dealing with right now, XSS.

I need to detect if a string contains XSS or not. In order to solve it I used that [link](http://codehustler.org/blog/jersey-cross-site-scripting-xss-filter-for-java-web-apps/). And this is the code I'm using:

```
public static boolean containsXSS(String value) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
        return false;
    }
    String stripXss = stripXSS(value);
    return !value.equals(stripXss);
}

public static String stripXSS(String value) {


 if (StringUtils.isBlank(value))
        return value;

    // Use the ESAPI library to avoid encoded attacks.
    Encoder encoder = ESAPI.encoder();
    value = encoder.canonicalize(value);

    // Avoid null characters
    value = value.replaceAll("\0", "");

    // Clean out HTML
    Document.OutputSettings outputSettings = new Document.OutputSettings();
    outputSettings.escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);
    outputSettings.prettyPrint(false);
    value = Jsoup.clean(value, "", Whitelist.none(), outputSettings);

    return value;
}
```

Using the code above I do succeed to catch things like: `<script>alert('xss')</script>`

My problem is that I identify the following string as containing XSS although it's not: 
{"item" :5}

It's because jsoup.clean turns it into `{&quot;item&quot; :5}`

I have tried to solve but with no success. 
It makes me wonder if my algorithm is **completely** wrong (if so where can I find the algorithm to detect XSS), perhaps I don't need to compare to the original String?

I would very appreciate if you could help me.

thanks

Comment: You can’t “detect if a string contains XSS”. Escape your output properly and XSS won’t be a problem.

Comment: Owasp provides sanitizers, use those

Comment: How do you escape properly? is'nt there a convention? should I use only apache.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot detect if a string contains XSS. XSS in an output issue, not an input issue. Data benign in one context, can cause malicious behaviour in another.

1. Validate data using white lists to ensure data is valid in your domain (numbers are numbers, names do not contain unwantef characters etc.). This will stop some but definitely not all attacks.
2. Contextually encode user provided output as explained in the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet
3. Dont mix client side and server side templates
4. Be careful when using unsanitized data in javascript (see DOM-based XSS)

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project contains information about the sanitizers provided by OWASP _plus_ links to the cheat sheet you named